# Shadow under cells of grouped uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i have `UITableView` with

- style -> grouped
- separator -> signle line etched clear color

Screenshot

[image]

And that's okay but i would like to change color of 'shadow' under cells. I think i've tried all background colors, tint colors, shadow colors etc and nothing... Can somebody help me?

Comment: you want to change  white line color of cell ???

Comment: yes, that's what i want to change

Comment: try the border or shadow colors of the individual cells.

Comment: cell.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
cell.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];

and lines are still white

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, i found a solution.
I've changed separator style to none and add shadow for each cell's layer

```
cell.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
cell.layer.shadowRadius = 0;
cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 1.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass the `UITableViewCell` that you are using and customize it any way you want. Then when you are implementing your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method you just set the cell to be one of your customized cells like this:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ExampleCell";
MyCustomTableViewCell *cell = (MyCustomTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
  cell = [[MyCustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 }
return cell;
```

Then an example of customizing the cell in your `MyCustomTableViewCell.m` file:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    if ((self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier])) {


    self.clipsToBounds = YES;

    UIView* bgView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    bgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.f alpha:0.25f];
    self.selectedBackgroundView = bgView;

    self.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
    self.textLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 2);
    self.textLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.25];

    UIView *topLine = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 1)];
    topLine.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.5 alpha:0.25];
    [self.textLabel.superview addSubview:topLine];

    UIView *bottomLine = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 43, 200, 1)];
    bottomLine.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.25];
    [self.textLabel.superview addSubview:bottomLine];

  }
  return self;
}
```

This gives you a look like: [image: this]. Sorry for the narrow image, but I didn't have time to redo the whole thing to get a wide cell.

Comment: well it's more complicated solution than i expected to find... and also i dono't how to set up a bottom line in last cell. I need to achive the same effect as on the screen and in your solution all lines are straight...